# CDI Interceptor and transaction propagation

Tags: java, cdi

I want to add an CDI Interceptor arround invocation of a EJB method.
The EJB is a business service @Stateless who have a CDI DAO injected in it.

```
@Stateless
class MyService {

    @Inject
    private DAO myDAO;

    @Workflow
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)    
    public void doStuff(MyData data) {
    //doing stuff 
    myDAO.edit(data);
    //doing others DAO stuff
    }    
}
```

Though the EJB is transactionnal by default, all the DAO invocations are in the same transaction, but now I want to add an Interceptor arround this method.

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Inherited
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Workflow {}

@Workflow
@Interceptor
public class WorkflowInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private transient Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private DAO myDAO;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object manage(final InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        ic.proceed();
        //do other stuff with DAO
        throw new ServiceException("OMG Error!");
    }

}
```

I want the DAO calls in the WorkflowInterceptor to be in the same transaction that the MyService. How can it be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You sure that it doesn't work out of the box? The [EJB 3.0 Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html) state, that "the AroundInvoke methods ... execute within the same transaction and security context as the business methods for which they are invoked."

Comment: When I throw an Exception from the interceptor, the JPA transaction is not break and is still commited. Perhaps does it need to be an RuntimeException?

Comment: What starts the transaction? What is the ejb client?

Comment: It's the EJB itself, when the client calls the method doStuff().

Comment: The client is generally a Struts2 Action or an REST EJB.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that something has to catch that exception and rollback the transaction. Rather than throwing the exception call setrollbackonly on an injected ejbcontext and then throw the exception if you still want it to propagate to the client.

Comment: It should work out-of-the-box. If you throw a `RuntimeException` then the transaction should be rolled back automatically. If you throw a checked `Exception` the transaction will not be rolled back. Unless the exception is annotated with `@ApplicationException(rollback = true)`

Comment: As a sidenote: The behavior described by Benjamin is EJB default behavior. As managed exceptions are part of the method signature, they are considered normal operation. By default, only a `RuntimeException` is considered as exceptional behavior and thus rolls back the transaction.

Comment: I changed to an RuntimeException and if I check the JPA log, I can see the rollback of the transaction. I'll try to catch it in the client side now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Interceptor is in the same transaction context. In the EJB world there are 2 kinds of exceptions:

- System exceptions (usually Runtime exceptions, but not always)
- Application exceptions (those are usually user defined [checked] exceptions and are present in the method signature - e.g. `void a() thows B`.)

The transaction is always rolled back automatically on system exceptions. But it's a programmer's responsibility to handle the transaction rollback on application exception. The other major difference is that system exceptions (unlike application exceptions) are wrapped in `EJBException` by the container and then re-thrown.

You can also make a user defined `RuntimeException` an `ApplicationException`, by annotating it with [`@ApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html). There you can specify if you want the transaction to be rolled back automatically or not, or if the @ApplicationException behavior should be inherited

Comment: Ok it seems to work, thanks! Very nice this @ApplicationException, I didn't know that!